# Google Map become scrollable while calculating zoome_changed event

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a google map with a lot of markers and polyline.

To avoid marker overlapping I had a function that group markers based on proximity. (Couldn't use a library as I needed custom text on grouped marker)

This is updated every time the user change the zoom level, so I have an zoom_changed event like that:

```
map.addListener('zoom_changed', function() {updatePoints(new google.maps.Size(12, 12)););});
```

Without getting into the detail of the function updatePoints it does freeze the map for a noticeable amount of time.

That in itself is not an issue, but when the user scrolls a bit to fast, the map when freezing suddenly become scrolable and the user scroll the page out of the map.

Is there any way to prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

I guesss **Marker Cluster** is what you need, check out this doc :
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering

Comment: Already read, But I need to modify the text on top of the regrouped marker. And I didn't find how to make this with that library.